# NetworkError on using prototype js

Tags: prototypejs, http-status-code-404

I have used a plugin that uses prototype js, it's working fine but the problem is it's requesting some other js files and shows me some NetworkError in firebug console. The plugin is working fine so i don't need other js file to include. Is there any way so that i can remove these errors? This is what i see in firebug console

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/builder.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/effects.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/controls.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/sound.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/slider.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/dragdrop.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/controls.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/slider.js"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://example.com/js/sound.js"
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I included the `prototype.js` and `scriptaculous.js` from google CDN (https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide) and now it didn't show any error and since these js are gzipped the plugin is loaded faster than before. Anyway thanks for the time in this question.

Comment: -1 since this is the answer that epoch gave you. If it didnt work, it appears you did not implement it correctly

Comment: @gbtimmon can you show me any config or implementation in his answer? he has just submitted the scripts to include which i had already done.

Answer (score 1):

The web page you are working on is trying to load Scriptaculous, the plugin probably needs it and your reference to it is not configured properly.

Prototype is not dependent on scriptaculous, it is the other way around. Can you tell me what is the plugin's name ?

**UPDATE**

Ok, As far as I can tell, there is nothing wrong with the plugin, make sure your include looks like the following (assuming your HTML is in the same folder):

```
<script src="prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="scriptaculous.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="dhonishow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: plugin name is dhonishow, here is the link `http://www.codefans.net/soft/5297.shtml`